# pam_ldap does not try simple bind when authenticating user

Tags: linux, authentication, ldap

I'm trying to make one test server to authenticate users against an 389 Directory Server LDAP. I've installed the nscd and nslcd, got them working. Commands like `getent passwd` work just fine.

Now I need to configure pam_ldap.so PAM module to autenticate users. The `man ldap_conf` states that:

> When authenticating or authorizing a user, pam_ldap first maps the user’s login name to a distinguished name by searching the directory server. This must be possible using the local system’s identity, specified in pam_ldap.conf. (Note that presently only simple authentication is supported for authenticating in this initial step.) **To  authenticate  a  user, pam_ldap attempts to bind to the directory server using the distinguished name of the user (retrieved previously). Both simple and SASL authentication mechanisms are supported**; in the former case, one should take care to use transport security to prevent the user’s password being transmitted in the clear.

However when trying to authenticate a user, the pam_ldap module does not perform a BIND against an LDAP server to try to authenticate the user.

/etc/nslcd.conf:

```
# nslcd daemon
uid nslcd
gid ldap

# ldap servers
uri ldaps://127.0.0.1:1636/
uri ldaps://127.0.0.1:1637/
ldap_version 3

# CA certificates for server certificate verification
ssl yes
tls_cacertfile /etc/ca.pem

#TODO: for testing only
tls_reqcert never

# limits
bind_timelimit 30
timelimit 30
idle_timelimit 600

# bind and globals
binddn uid=proxytest,ou=proxies,c=gb
bindpw 123456789
base o=company,c=gb
scope sub

# users
base passwd ou=people,o=company,c=gb
scope passwd sub
filter passwd (objectClass=posixAccount)

# groups
base group ou=group,o=company,c=gb
scope group sub
filter group (objectClass=posixGroup)
```

/etc/openldap/ldap.conf (it has defaults, it should be good because I overrode everything in the pam_ldap.conf):

```
# LDAP Defaults
#
# See ldap.conf(5) for details
# This file should be world readable but not world writable.
#URI        ldap://localhost:1389 ldap://localhost:1390
#SIZELIMIT  12
#TIMELIMIT  15
#DEREF      never
TLS_CACERTDIR   /etc/openldap/certs
```

/etc/pam_ldap.conf:

```
# @(#)$Id: ldap.conf,v 1.38 2006/05/15 08:13:31 lukeh Exp $
#
# The man page for this file is pam_ldap(5)
#
# PADL Software
# http://www.padl.com
#

base ou=people,o=company,c=gb

uri ldaps://127.0.0.1:1636/
uri ldaps://127.0.0.1:1637/
ldap_version 3

binddn uid=proxytest,ou=proxies,c=gb
bindpw 123456789

scope sub
timelimit 30
bind_timelimit 30

bind_policy hard
idle_timelimit 600

pam_filter objectclass=posixAccount
pam_login_attribute uid

# Group member attribute
pam_member_attribute memberUid

ssl on
#TODO: for testing only
tls_checkpeer no

# CA certificates for server certificate verification
tls_cacertfile /etc/ca.pem
```

/etc/nsswitch.conf:

```
...
passwd:     files ldap
shadow:     files ldap
group:      files ldap
...
```

With this configuration, the authentication works just fine. The thing is the server goes with reading user's shadow information from the LDAP server with pam_unix module (through nss) - which effectively means that the module reads userPassword out of the LDAP and compares it locally. **That is what I do not want to happen.** When looking at the LDAP logs (and also on unencrypted network traffic), there is no evidence the system tries to bind under the user who is attemtping to log in:

```
[19/May/2017:15:20:19 +0200] conn=213 op=0 BIND dn="uid=proxytest,ou=proxies,c=gb" method=128 version=3
[19/May/2017:15:20:19 +0200] conn=213 op=0 RESULT err=0 tag=97 nentries=0 etime=0 dn="uid=proxytest,ou=proxies,c=gb"

[19/May/2017:15:20:19 +0200] conn=213 op=1 SRCH base="ou=people,o=company,c=gb" scope=2 filter="(&(objectClass=posixAccount)(uid=test))" attrs="userPassword cn gidNumber uidNumber loginShell objectClass gecos uid homeDirectory"
[19/May/2017:15:20:19 +0200] conn=213 op=1 RESULT err=0 tag=101 nentries=1 etime=0

[19/May/2017:15:20:19 +0200] conn=205 op=12 SRCH base="ou=people,o=company,c=gb" scope=2 filter="(&(objectClass=posixAccount)(uid=test))" attrs="uid"
[19/May/2017:15:20:19 +0200] conn=205 op=12 RESULT err=0 tag=101 nentries=1 etime=0

[19/May/2017:15:20:19 +0200] conn=205 op=13 SRCH base="ou=group,o=company,c=gb" scope=2 filter="(&(objectClass=posixGroup)(|(memberUid=test)(uniqueMember=uid=test,ou=people,o=company,c=gb)))" attrs="cn userPassword memberUid gidNumber uniqueMember"
[19/May/2017:15:20:19 +0200] conn=205 op=13 RESULT err=0 tag=101 nentries=0 etime=0 notes=U
```

Even rearranging PAM modules so the `pam_ldap.so` goes before `pam_unix.so` does not affect this behavior. I'm trying this on CentOS 6.8 x86_64 with `pam_ldap-185-11.el6.x86_64`, other libraries:

```
rpm -qa | grep -E "ldap|nss|nscd|nslc"
apr-util-ldap-1.3.9-3.el6_0.1.x86_64
openldap-2.4.40-16.el6.x86_64
pam_ldap-185-11.el6.x86_64
nss-util-3.28.4-1.el6_9.x86_64
nss-sysinit-3.28.4-1.el6_9.x86_64
nss-pam-ldapd-0.7.5-32.el6.x86_64
openldap-clients-2.4.40-16.el6.x86_64
nss-3.28.4-1.el6_9.x86_64
nss-tools-3.28.4-1.el6_9.x86_64
nscd-2.12-1.209.el6_9.1.x86_64
nss-softokn-freebl-3.14.3-23.3.el6_8.x86_64
nss-softokn-3.14.3-23.3.el6_8.x86_64
```

Also, the relevant pam.d configuration:

```
cat /etc/pam.d/password-auth
#%PAM-1.0
auth        required      pam_warn.so
auth        required      pam_env.so
auth        sufficient    pam_unix.so nullok try_first_pass
auth        requisite     pam_succeed_if.so uid >= 500 quiet
auth        sufficient    pam_ldap.so use_first_pass
auth        required      pam_deny.so

account     required      pam_unix.so
account     sufficient    pam_localuser.so
account     sufficient    pam_succeed_if.so uid < 500 quiet
account     [default=bad success=ok user_unknown=ignore] pam_ldap.so
account     required      pam_permit.so

password    requisite     pam_cracklib.so try_first_pass retry=3 type=
password    sufficient    pam_unix.so sha512 shadow nullok try_first_pass use_authtok
password    required      pam_deny.so

session     optional      pam_keyinit.so revoke
session     required      pam_limits.so
session     [success=1 default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so service in crond quiet use_uid
session     required      pam_unix.so
session     optional      pam_ldap.so
```

Is there any way of forcing the pam_ldap.so module to do the LDAP bind under the `uid=test,ou=people,o=company,c=gb` user? I understand the library will first look its DN in the LDAP and I'm perfectly fine with it.
I'm currently out of ideas so even hints are appreciated. :)

Comment: Which pam_ldap are you using? The one that comes with nslcd? The (obsolete) one from PADL?

Comment: There is only one pam_ldap.so. Running `yum whatprovides *bin/nslcd` gives me the `nss-pam-ldapd` package which I get to deplist. And `yum deplist nss-pam-ldapd` shows me as an only provider of pam_ldap.so the `pam_ldap.x86_64 185-11.el6` package. But considering the config file's header this is probably the PADL version. But nevermind, I made a mistake, the whole thing actually works. :-/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was actually the "end-of-the-week" problem. Config in question works perfectly fine.

The point here was there are two LDAP servers and by a mere chance the operation of `BIND uid=test,ou=people,o=company,c=gb` was performed against the other ldap than I was looking into (like 20 or more times actually; bad luck). Also did not appear in the network dump because I managed to make a mistake in the BPF for the tcpdump.